# Condition Variables and the Use of Locks

Tags: java, multithreading

I am currently trying to implement a linked list that is thread-protected. One of the methods to implement is take(), which removes the most recently added element, and waits for an element to be added if the list is empty. My knowledge of Java threads and synchronization is pretty shoddy, so I'd like to know if this implementation works. Particularly, I'd like to know what happens if take() is called before put(). Since they both use the same lock object, I feel as though if take() is called before put(), the lock for take() is never released, so put() will be stuck trying to get that lock(). Here is my implementation

```
//Globals
private final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
final Condition notEmpty = lock.newCondition();

 public boolean put(int address) {
    Node newnode = new Node(null, null, address);
    lock.lock();
    if(first == null) {
        try {
            first = newnode;
            last = newnode;
            size++;
            notEmpty.signal();
        }
        finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
    else {
        if(contains(address) == true) {
            remove(address);
        }

        first.prev = newnode;
        newnode.next = first;
        first = newnode;
        size++;
    }

    return true;
}
```

For the take

```
    public int take() throws InterruptedException {
      lock.lock();
      try{
          while(size() == 0)
              notEmpty.await();
          remove();
      }
      finally {
          lock.unlock();
      }
  }
```

Any help would be great! Thanks.

Comment: have you tried testing it to see if your suspicions are correct?

Comment: More than seeing if it is right, I am having trouble understanding how this synch would work since it seems like the one lock() i'm using would never be released. But, in almost every implementation i've seen online, they use only one lock and use it as I have.

Comment: Did you tried to read any docs about functions you use? `notEmpty.await()` releases the lock while it waits, and acquires it after waiting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should consider using "[java.util.Stack](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html)".

Java stack is already synchronized and has methods pop() and push() which you can call from take() and put() without worrying about locks.

now all you need to do is wait in take() if the stack object is empty, you can setup a listener for the stack object, or you initiate a class parameter 
`int takeCalled = 0` 
and increase it every time take() is called with empty stack:

```
public void take(){
    if (stackObj.isempty()) takeCalled++;
    else stackObj.pop();
}
```

and then do a simple check in put() to empty the stack if `takeCalled > 0`

```
public void put(x){
    stackObj.push(x);
    while(!stackObj.isEmpty()) take();
}
```

I always prefer to use the synchronized build in implementation as you cannot grantee bugs free logic. for example your put will not release the lock if `first != null`.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever the `put(..)` method will be executed upon a non empty list (meaning, `first != null`) the lock will never be released, because in your implementation of the `put(..)`method you `lock()` the lock before the `if(first == null)` statement, and release it only if the condition is true, and if it doesn't (the execution goes into `else`), you never release the lock, preventing any other thread to ever take it in the future.

You must make sure the lock is released as soon as possible, in **every** execution.